# How to allow anonymous creator of page to make changes, while preventing public access?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a simple form that can be filled in and saved by users without logging in. I want the user to be able to view and make changes to the form they complete for the duration of their visit, while preventing anybody else from accessing the page (i.e. via /page/1 or page/edit/1).

How can I do this without making the user create an account immediately?

Thanks.

Comment: I only see one way: check session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd store in session the `id` of the created pages. It would be straight to check whether or not one page belongs to the user or not.

Comment: Is that secure - could it be faked to gain access to another user's page?

Comment: it's safe: it's even used to store `id` of a `current_user` when logged in. check: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html